# R Merging Map ShapeFiles Together

Tags: r, shapefile

I am attempting to merge two shapefiles together in R to plot.

I have downloaded the ShapeFile format of the political boundaries of the Carribbean from [here](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1997/ofr-97-470/OF97-470K/graphic/data.html) and the ShapeFile of U.S. county borders from this [link](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2017&layergroup=Counties%20%28and%20equivalent%29).

I have read in both files with

```
US_counties <- shapefile("~/us_county_shp_files/tl_2017_us_county.shp")
carribbean <-  shapefile("~/pol6bg/pol6bg.shp")
```

From looking at other posts, I have tried using both the union and the rbind methods.

With rbind (shown below), I get the error: identicalCRS(dots) is not TRUE.

```
rbind(US_counties, carribbean, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)
```

With union, I get Error in as.vector(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector.

```
union(US_counties, carribbean)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the error when using `union` seems to arise due to conflicting packages. In particular, not the right function `union` is being called. Using

```
raster:::union(US_counties, carribbean)
```

gives

```
Warning message:
In union(US_counties, carribbean) : non identical CRS
```

which possibly is an important warning and says the same as when trying to use `rbind. Perhaps you know more about CRS (Coordinate Reference Systems) than me, but the problem is that

```
proj4string(carribbean)
# [1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
proj4string(US_counties)
# [1] "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

So, not very surprisingly, the two shape files are of somewhat different formats. With the help of [this](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/OverviewCoordinateReferenceSystems.pdf) useful read we see that it's not hard to unify those formats, after all. E.g.,

```
library(sp)
carribbean <- spTransform(carribbean, proj4string(US_counties))
```

Then

```
rbind(US_counties, carribbean, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)
# Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
#   numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

still doesn't work, but the problem is clear given that we are trying to bind different variables

```
names(US_counties)
#  [1] "STATEFP"  "COUNTYFP" "COUNTYNS" "GEOID"    "NAME"     "NAMELSAD" "LSAD"     "CLASSFP" 
#  [9] "MTFCC"    "CSAFP"    "CBSAFP"   "METDIVFP" "FUNCSTAT" "ALAND"    "AWATER"   "INTPTLAT"
# [17] "INTPTLON"
names(carribbean)
# [1] "F_CODE"     "NAM"        "NA2"        "NA2_DESCRI" "NA3"        "NA3_DESCRI" "WFBPATHLN" 
# [8] "AREA"       "PERIMETER"
```

However,

```
raster:::union(US_counties, carribbean)
```

now works and shows no warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Julius! When I try to replicate your code, I get this error from the union method call: Error in as.vector(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector. Is it because of a package I am missing?

Comment: @Alan, see the update. It was actually more about too many packages rather than missing something.