Merge two shapefiles in R, get a dataframe of variable value in each precinct
I'm not a GIS person, this is driving me nuts. I have a shp file of voting precincts. I have another shp file of radio broadcasts. I want to use R to geolocate the broadcasts into the precincts, so that I get a dataframe that records the signal strength in each precinct. This should be a basic merge but I am unfamiliar with GIS in R. Sorry for the basic question, really appreciate your help!! Here is what I have tried:
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(mapview)
library(raster)
#library(rvest)
#library(httr)


# load precinct data
ks <- readOGR(paste(datadir,("Precincts/KS/ks_2020/ks_2020.shp"),sep="")) 
#plot(ks) # plots all the different variables

# load coverage shp file 
br <- readOGR(paste(datadir,("CloudRF/0606082117_Radio_catchment_SHP_K275BQ.shp"),sep="")) 
#plot(br)

# different projections, need to fix
projection(ks)
projection(br)

proj4string(ks)
proj4string(br)

crs(br) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs" # assign ks projection

plot(ks["VTDST"])
plot(br,add=T,col="red") # close but not aligned correctly 

#### try 2: unify method, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378845/r-merging-map-shapefiles-together

br2 <- spTransform(br, proj4string(ks))
x = rbind(ks, br2, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE) # Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : numbers of columns of arguments do not match
y = raster::union(ks, br2) # takes forever, does not seem to work




While it is appreciated that it is difficult to know where to start if you are new to coding in R, SO is not a code writing service. Proof that you have at least made some attempt to solve this yourself is expected. To that end, what have you tried so far? Did you search SO for similar questions? Also, a shapefile is not a single file, it is a composite of multiple files (minimum three) - .shp, .dbf , .shx, .prj, .sbn ... - each with the same file prefix. The links you added are only for the .shp part. Please address these concerns so that your question conforms to SO standards. Good luck!

@LTyrone Fair enough, added code, didn't get very far despite my best efforts though

Few issues to address 1) You state "close but not aligned correctly". Where are you expecting the coverage object relative to the precinct object? Should the coverage object be overlapping just with the Kansas precincts of Kansas City? 2) what do you mean by "signal strength? Percentage of precinct covered by coverage? The DN value of the coverage objects that overlap with a given precinct? A combination of the two?

Just to illustrate previous comments, when overlaid, shapes look like this - https://i.sstatic.net/L7pvSSdr.png ; and when zoomed in - https://i.sstatic.net/f5jVuIA6.png .  I'm afraid you'd need to describe your desired output bit more. From "basic merge" I'd assume that you'd just want to know which precincts intersect with broadcast polygons (DN is either 37 or 49, in most precincts both are present, so with with just intersects, recorded DN values can basically be ignored).  But " dataframe that records the signal strength in each precinct" does not seem to align with that assumption.

@LTyrone 1) Ok, I see this is ok now, my error. 2) Ideally it would be great to make two variables: a) % precinct covered by coverage, and b) mean DN value in that precinct. Thank you!

The function sf::st_intersection() is useful to achieve what you want. However, it expects a projected coordinate system (PCS) and you have indicated that you want your data to have a geographic coordinate system (GCS). In order to get this to work, you need to tell R to treat GCS values (NAD83:EPSG4269 in this case) as planar. Alternatively, you could project your data to an appropriate PCS first. This example uses the former.
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)
options(scipen = 999) # For illustrative purposes

# Load coverage.shp as sf objects and check metadata
coverage <- st_read("coverage.shp")

coverage
# Simple feature collection with 33451 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -94.85073 ymin: 38.74753 xmax: -94.16655 ymax: 39.28515
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# First 10 features:
#    DN                       geometry
# 1  49 POLYGON ((-94.51442 39.2851...
# 2  37 POLYGON ((-94.51408 39.2851...
# 3  37 POLYGON ((-94.5134 39.28515...
# 4  49 POLYGON ((-94.51068 39.2851...
# 5  37 POLYGON ((-94.48926 39.2851...
# 6  49 POLYGON ((-94.52904 39.2848...
# 7  49 POLYGON ((-94.52836 39.2848...
# 8  49 POLYGON ((-94.52292 39.2848...
# 9  49 POLYGON ((-94.51374 39.2851...
# 10 49 POLYGON ((-94.51306 39.2848...

# Load precincts.shp, remove Z coordinates, unique id, check metadata
precincts <- st_read("ks_2020.shp") %>%
  st_zm() %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n(),
         p_area = as.numeric(st_area(.)))

precincts
# Simple feature collection with 4062 features and 2 fields
# Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -102.0518 ymin: 36.99302 xmax: -94.58839 ymax: 40.00317
# Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
# First 10 features:
#                          geometry id     p_area
# 1  MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.42748 3...  1 77743557.2
# 2  MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.46656 3...  2 96520944.9
# 3  MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.33574 3...  3 93712595.6
# 4  MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.47322 3...  4 65046236.9
# 5  MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.40017 3...  5  2815018.5
# 6  MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.31745 3...  6 78390113.8
# 7  MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.37257 3...  7 47064895.3
# 8  MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.51943 3...  8 78180749.2
# 9  MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.23385 3...  9 61499294.4
# 10 MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.43395 3... 10   107387.3

# Project coverage so crs matches precincts
coverage <- st_transform(coverage, 4269)

# Turn of S2 processing (as CRS is GCS and st_intersection() expects planar CRS)
sf_use_s2(FALSE)

# Intersect sf objects and calculate % intersection and mean DN
# Warnings telling you data are not in an expected planar CRS
p_c_int <- st_intersection(precincts, coverage) %>%
  mutate(c_area = as.numeric(st_area(.))) %>%
  summarise(pc_area = 100 / first(p_area) * sum(c_area),
            dn_mean = mean(DN),
            .by = c(id),
            across(geometry, st_union))

p_c_int
# Simple feature collection with 376 features and 3 fields
# Geometry type: GEOMETRY
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -94.85073 ymin: 38.76079 xmax: -94.60728 ymax: 39.16477
# Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
# First 10 features:
#      id   pc_area  dn_mean                       geometry
# 1  2925 15.801974 46.92308 MULTIPOLYGON (((-94.72423 3...
# 2  2908  8.863159 47.58824 MULTIPOLYGON (((-94.7579 39...
# 3  2902 34.393521 47.72727 MULTIPOLYGON (((-94.70218 3...
# 4  2918  7.649041 47.01325 MULTIPOLYGON (((-94.69091 3...
# 5  2905 65.939722 47.00000 MULTIPOLYGON (((-94.73375 3...
# 6  2827 71.485757 46.81818 MULTIPOLYGON (((-94.6637 39...
# 7  2924 17.108637 47.34483 MULTIPOLYGON (((-94.7204 39...
# 8  2923  2.517207 46.93103 MULTIPOLYGON (((-94.81209 3...
# 9  2849 22.864621 47.55172 MULTIPOLYGON (((-94.64753 3...
# 10 2852 69.181971 46.80000 MULTIPOLYGON (((-94.65343 3...

# left_join() (for illustrative purposes only)
precincts <- precincts %>%
  left_join(., select(data.frame(p_c_int), c(id, pc_area)), by = "id")

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = precincts, 
          aes(fill = pc_area),
          colour = NA) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#F0E442", high = "#DF536B", na.value = "grey90",
                      name = "% Coverage") +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_sf(data = p_c_int, aes(fill = dn_mean), colour = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = precincts,
          fill = NA,
          linewidth = .15) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#0072B2", high = "#490092",
                      name = "Mean DN") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-94.90875, -94.58839),
           ylim = c(38.73808, 39.19147)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())


It is a good habit to turn S2 processing back on after you are done by using:
sf_use_s2(TRUE)

